# Json string is cut off at 2032 bytes

Tags: php, json, sql-server, sqlsrv

I have many stored procedures that return a query result as one Json string.  Following is a sample of the query in one of my stored procedures that returns JSON using the Microsoft SQL Server's `FOR JSON` feature:

```sql
SELECT 
    V.* 
FROM 
    ClassPerson CP
INNER JOIN 
    PersonActive PA ON (CONVERT(nvarchar(128), PA.PersonActiveId) = @usrGuid AND CP.PersonId = PA.personId)
INNER JOIN 
    ClassPerson CP2 ON (CP2.classId = CP.ClassId)
INNER JOIN 
    V_Student V ON (V.PersonId = CP2.PersonId)
FOR JSON PATH, ROOT('AllRecord')
```

And this is the string that the above query can return:

```json
{
    "AllRecord": [
        {
            "PersonId": 179,
            "VN_ID": "VN 1557",
            "FirstName": "Selena",
            "LastName": "Le",
            "BirthDate": "2012-07-10",
            "Gender": "Female",
            "Profession": "S",
            "HomePhone": 3127314009,
            "Father": "Lê p. Nguyen",
            "FatherPhone": 3127314009,
            "Mother": "Ho  Thu",
            "MotherPhone": 3127314009,
            "EmergencyContact": "Nguyen ngoc Hien",
            "Member": "N",
            "ActiveFlag": 1,
            "DateCreated": "2021-05-22T19:15:07.290",
            "Modified": "1900-01-01T00:00:06.797",
            "ModifierName": "dbo",
            "AddressId": 219,
            "EmailId": 181,
            "Street1": "4014 Two Bridge Ct",
            "City": "Buford",
            "StateAbr": "GA",
            "ZipCode": "30518",
            "Email": "nguyenle17@gmail.com"
        }
    ]
}
```

The problem is that, if the query returns multiple records, PHP code chopped of at byte #2033, making the Json string invalid. I tried many different way of fetching, but it is still the same. Note that all my stored procedures work just fine with C#.

Is there a way to increase the maximum string in php to a few millions of bytes?  I mean is the real world out there, 2032 bytes max is a joke.

Comment: This doesn't seem like a `sql-server` issue, rather a `php` issue. Please share the PHP you are using that is causing your data to be chopped off and update the tags so it catches the eye of php experts.

Comment: I'd say the .... unusual thing is trying to export a million-byte long string with SQL commands. This increases the size of the transferred data drastically for no benefit. Assuming it made sense to export data as JSON (dubious), it would be a lot faster to read the data normally and export it to a JSON file *on the client*

Comment: In C# it would be very easy to execute a query and read each row using a DataReader, serialize the row using eg Json.NET in unindented form and append the line to the target file. This would only consume the memory needed to keep a single row and line in memory, instead of million-character-long strings

Comment: Read about the [Output of the FOR JSON clause](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/json/format-query-results-as-json-with-for-json-sql-server?view=sql-server-2017#output-of-the-for-json-clause). (althought 2032 bytes is short ebough) You may try to change the way the JSON is fetched. But, if possible, post the relevant PHP code. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Put the JSON query inside another `SELECT`:

```sql
SELECT (
    SELECT V.* FROM ClassPerson CP
        INNER JOIN PersonActive PA ON(CONVERT(nvarchar(128),PA.PersonActiveId) = @usrGuid AND CP.PersonId = PA.personId)
        INNER JOIN ClassPerson CP2 ON(CP2.classId = CP.ClassId)
        INNER JOIN V_Student V ON(V.PersonId = CP2.PersonId)
        FOR JSON PATH, ROOT('AllRecord')
);
-- alternatively
DECLARE @json nvarchar(max) = (
    SELECT V.* FROM ClassPerson CP
        INNER JOIN PersonActive PA ON(CONVERT(nvarchar(128),PA.PersonActiveId) = @usrGuid AND CP.PersonId = PA.personId)
        INNER JOIN ClassPerson CP2 ON(CP2.classId = CP.ClassId)
        INNER JOIN V_Student V ON(V.PersonId = CP2.PersonId)
        FOR JSON PATH, ROOT('AllRecord')
);

SELECT @json;
```